# Know if an element can potentially fit another element on window resize

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, window-resize

I'm looking for a way to know if a an element (a menu) can potentially fit into another element on window resize. I do not know the width of the element in question (as in, it's not set by CSS).

The content of the menu is dynamic and unknown in data (language) and count (user role/permissions).

The solution I can come up with works fine if my first load happens to have the element fitting, because I store the initial width, but it doesn't work so well if the element doesn't fit (say at a reduced window size). So my question, how can I handle this upsizing?

**Sample HTML/CSS:**
Look at the snippet in full screen ("expand snippet"). It breaks off at about 604 pixels, and the responsive menu kicks off at 480px.

```css
.header {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
}

.header__logo {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.menu {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}

.menu__item {
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__logo">logo</div>
  <div class="hamburger">=</div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item">item 1</li>
    <li class="menu__item">item 2</li>
    <li class="menu__item">item 3</li>
    <li class="menu__item">item 4</li>
    <li class="menu__item">item 5</li>
    <li class="menu__item">item 6</li>
    <li class="menu__item">item 7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "how can I handle this"? What is the desired outcome at the intermediate width between mobile menu and when everything fits?

Comment: Well the desired outcome could a more compact version (with icons), or just falling the hamburger. However, I'm not particularly interested with the outcome, I'm more interested with knowing when it doesn't fit. I guess the compact version would be a problematic case.

Comment: just another quick question: will the text in the `<li>` be inside an `<a>`?

Comment: Yes, there will be anchors inside the list items :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries and something like [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) (there are also other options) to display/hide icons and text at specific break points. You can resize your screen to find the pixel values.

If you are looking for a JS example to find out specific widths, that can be done too - but if this can be solved by CSS, why not!

```css
.header {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
}
.header__logo {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.menu {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
.menu__item {
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.hamburger {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
}
.menu__item .fa {
  display: none;
}
li.menu__item a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
/*(min-width:465px) and (max-width:545px) */
/* or whatever widths you need */
@media all and (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .menu__item a span {
    color: salmon;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .menu__item a .fa {
    display: block;
    text-indent: 0;
    color: #a00;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__logo">logo</div>
  <div class="hamburger">=</div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>item 1</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>item 2</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>item 3</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>item 4</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>item 5</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>item 6</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>item 7</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, in my case, it cannot be handled purely by CSS, as my menu is different depending on user and permissions. Plus it could be in different languages, so I cannot trust that 1000px: My admin menu, with 6 items is ~1068 pixels wide, I don't know how wide it will be in another language, if I change a translation or term.

Comment: ah... that would have been helpful to know! I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Indeed, sorry for the confusion

Comment: I've come up with a little JS solution that handles resizing pretty nicely.

Comment: @veksen you should answer your own question then - might help others, and I'd like to see it too!

Comment: I did, see me answer!

Comment: @veksen ah! I was on my phone and didn't see. Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

So I have come up with a solution that works pretty well. It is heavily inspired of the work of [Ridiculously Responsive Social Sharing Buttons](https://github.com/kni-labs/rrssb)

```
var Menu = (function() {
  // setup classes used
  var headerClass = 'header__wrapper';
  var elClass = 'main-nav';
  var itemsClass = 'main-nav__item';
  var smallClass = itemsClass + '--small';

  // setup jQuery elements
  var $header = $('.' + headerClass).not('.clone');

  // setup the clone used to make operations/checks
  var clone = '.clone.' + headerClass;

  // currently, only a set height is supported
  var originalHeight = 60;

  var stealth = function(el) {
    var $el = (el instanceof jQuery) ? el : $(el);

    $el.css({
      height: 'auto',
      // position absolute is needed to be out of the DOM structure,
      // while still having a testable height
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      visibility: 'hidden'
    });
  }

  return {
    init() {
      Menu.reset();
      Menu.exec();
      Menu.bindEvents();
    },

    exec() {
      // create a clone if it doesn't exist
      if (!$(clone).length) {
        Menu.clone(clone);
      }

      // reset the menu to its largest form
      Menu.reset();

      // does it fit?
      if (Menu.checkFit()) {
        // it fits, use the clone data;
        Menu.replace();
      } else {
        // it didn't fit, so attempt to fit
        Menu.attemptToFit();
      }
    },

    reset() {
      $(clone).find('.' + itemsClass).removeClass(smallClass);
    },

    bindEvents() {
      $(window).resize(function() {
        Menu.exec();
      });

      $(window).focus(function() {
        Menu.exec();
      });
    },

    checkFit() {
      return $(clone).height() == originalHeight;
    },

    attemptToFit() {
      var itemsArr = $(clone).find('.' + itemsClass).sort(function(a, b) {
        // TODO: handle and make sure nodes without data-priority are handled by DOM order
        var a = $(a).attr('data-priority') || 0;
        var b = $(b).attr('data-priority') || 0;

        return b - a;
      });

      // count iterations that do not fit
      var noFit = 0;

      // cycle over items, attempting to fit
      itemsArr.each(function(i) {
        var item = itemsArr[i];

        $(item).addClass(smallClass);

        // exit the loop if it fits!
        if (Menu.checkFit()) {
          // it fits, exit the loop!

          return false;
        } else {
          // this attempt didn't fit, try the next done
          noFit++;
        }
      });

      // could we make it fit?
      if (noFit == itemsArr.length - 1) {
        // TODO: handle this scenario
        // couldn't make it fit :( handle it
      } else {
        // we were able to make it fit, replace the original with the clone content
        Menu.replace();
      }
    },

    clone(el) {
      $header.clone().addClass('clone').insertAfter($header);
      stealth(el);
    },

    replace() {
      var content = $(clone).clone().contents();

      // replace the content of the original with the clone
      $header.empty().append(content);
    }
  };

})();

Menu.init();
```

See it in action on CodePen: http://codepen.io/veksen/pen/ORAmVa